# Accessing query inline calendar value in django

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to get the date value from a jquery inline datepicker
calendar in django.

The challenge for me is the "inline" calendar is called on a "div" vs
"input" so I don't access the value through a django form.

The code below seems to work great in displaying the calender inline
and I think "getDate" is creating a django date object. I'm just not
sure how to access that value in my view.py?

I'm fairly inexperienced with jquery so and feedback/guidance I can get is helpful

Appreciate the feedback!

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>

<script>
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      var dateAsString = dateText; //the first parameter of this function
      var dateAsObject = $(this).datepicker( 'getDate' ); //the getDate method
       }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass a Jquery variable directly to view.py. You can do an ajax post to the view.py if you want to pass the data in the variable. Or you can create a hidden input field and assign it's value to be the value of the datepicker and then submit the form.